# Why strange operator precedence in Nim macro?

Tags: nim-lang

This example won't compile, why?

```
macro somefn*(arg) =
  echo $(arg).to_upper()

somefn arg
```

Error:

```
Error: type mismatch: got <NimNode>
but expected one of: 
proc toUpper(c: Rune): Rune
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for c: Rune
  but expression 'arg' is of type: NimNode
proc toUpper(s: string): string
  first type mismatch at position: 1
  required type for s: string
  but expression 'arg' is of type: NimNode
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#syntax-precedence):

> Unary operators always bind stronger than any binary operator: $a + b
> is ($a) + b and not $(a + b).

As such it binds to the entire first expression and not the parenthesis. If you wanted to you could do

```
echo `$`(arg).to_upper()
```